# Why can't I replace Ellipsis using `pd.DataFrame.replace`?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace, ellipsis

I have this following `pd.DataFrame`:

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'b': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'c': [1.2, 3.4, 5.6, 7.8], 'd': [..., ..., ..., ...]})
>>> df
   a  b    c         d
0  1  a  1.2  Ellipsis
1  2  b  3.4  Ellipsis
2  3  c  5.6  Ellipsis
3  4  d  7.8  Ellipsis
>>>
```

I am trying to replace the Ellipsis with `1`.

I know I could do something like:

```py
>>> df.mask(df == Ellipsis, 1)
   a  b    c  d
0  1  a  1.2  1
1  2  b  3.4  1
2  3  c  5.6  1
3  4  d  7.8  1
>>>
```

But, for some reason. If I do:

```
df.replace(..., 1)
```

Or:

```
df.replace(Ellipsis, 1)
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Expecting 'to_replace' to be either a scalar, array-like, dict or None, got invalid type 'ellipsis'
```

Why doesn't `replace` allow me to replace `Ellipsis`?

I know how to fix it, I want to know why this happens.

---

The strange thing here is that, I actually can replace numbers with Ellipsis, but not vice versa.

Example:

```
>>> df.replace(1, ...)
          a  b    c         d
0  Ellipsis  a  1.2  Ellipsis
1         2  b  3.4  Ellipsis
2         3  c  5.6  Ellipsis
3         4  d  7.8  Ellipsis
>>>
```

---

The even stranger thing here mentioned by @jezrael and @phœnix is that:

```
df.replace({Ellipsis: 1})
```

Also:

```
df.replace({...: 1})
```

As well as:

```
df.replace([Ellipsis], 1)
```

And:

```
df.replace([...], 1)
```

Work as expected!

It gives:

```
   a  b    c  d
0  1  a  1.2  1
1  2  b  3.4  1
2  3  c  5.6  1
3  4  d  7.8  1
```

Comment: For me working `df =  df.replace({Ellipsis: 1})` only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion it is bug, so reported [BUG: Can't I replace Ellipsis in DataFrame.replace like scalar #50373](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/50373) .

Answer (score 2):

you can use this :

```
df['d']=df['d'].replace(to_replace=[...],value=(1))
```

or

```
df=df.replace(to_replace=[...],value=(1))
```

Comment: That's cool! But do you know why this happens?

Comment: because Ellipsis is just str(...)

Comment: It's type is `Ellipsis` though, not `str`.

Comment: yes exact  type is Ellipsis and  str(...)=Ellipsis

Comment: It's a bug. @jezrael reported it on GitHub.

Comment: i see that , thanks to @jezrael